# Jquery Validation not working at all?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

Not sure what I am doing wrong here,  But for some reason, my Jquery Validation code is messing up my site...

Just a little background, I am implementing a asp.net MVC2 website that will display a datatable from XML that I get from the controller.  I am thinking about getting JSON data from the controller, but I need to get something working.  Anyway, So All of my rows and columns, are generated on the fly.  Now I have a windows that is modal pop up window (which is essentially just an ascx file...) I generate the form similarly off the fly using xml that I get from the controller.  Putting Jquery validation elements in there can be a little harrowing.  Here is what I attempted to do...

```
    foreach (string row in paths)
  {
      Response.Write(String.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>", row));
      System.Xml.XmlAttributeCollection nodes = TemplateToEdit.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("./elements/element[@name='{0}']", row)).Attributes;
      System.Xml.XmlNode validationNode = TemplateToEdit.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("./elements/element/validation", row));
      if ((nodes["readOnly"].Value == "false") || (nodes["visable"].Value == "true"))
      {
          if (validationNode != null)
          {
              System.Xml.XmlNode rule = validationNode.SelectSingleNode("./rules/rule");
              System.Xml.XmlAttributeCollection ruleAttributes = rule.Attributes;
              //ruleAttributes["test"]
          }
          //initialVal = xTemplate.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[@value='{0}']", paths[i])).Value;
          switch (nodes["dataType"].Value)
          {
              case "String":
                  if (row == "MRNType")
                  { 
                     %><label for="<%row %>"><%=Html.DropDownList(string.Format("{0}", row), (List<SelectListItem>)TempData["MRNLIST"])%></label><%
                  }
                  else{
                    %><label for="<%row %>">
                    <%=Html.TextBox(string.Format("{0}", paths[i]), (nodes["value"].Value == null ? "" : nodes["value"].Value), new { id = nodes["id"].Value, @class = "{validate:true, "+paths[i]+":true, messages:{required:'Please enter a value'}}" })%></label><!--string input -->                        
                    <% Response.Write("</td>");                        
                       }
                    %><%
                       break;
              case "int":
                    Response.Write("");                    
                    %><label for="<%row %>"><%=Html.TextBox(string.Format("{0}", paths[i]), (nodes["value"].Value == null ? "" : nodes["value"].Value), new { id = nodes["id"].Value, @class = "{validate:true, " + paths[i] + ":true, messages:{required:'Please enter a value'}}" })%></label> <!--string input --><%
                    Response.Write("</td>");
                    break;
              case "KeyValuePair":
                    Response.Write("");
                    %><%=Html.RadioButton(string.Format("{0}", paths[i]), "1", new { id = nodes["id"].Value })%>Yes<%
                    %><%=Html.RadioButton(string.Format("{0}", paths[i]), "0", new { id = nodes["id"].Value })%>No<%
                    Response.Write("</td>");
                    break;
              case "Date":
                    %><label for="<%row %>"><%=Html.TextBox(string.Format("{0}", paths[i]), (row.Contains("Date") ? nodes["value"].Value : row), new { @class = "datepicker" + dateCount, Class = "{validate:true, " + paths[i] + ":true, messages:{required:'Please enter a value'}}" })%></label><!--supposed to be date input --><%
                    Response.Write("</td>");
                    dateCount++;
                    break;
          }
          Response.Write("</tr>");
      }
      i++;
  }
```

As you can see, quite confusing.  But let me break it down for you, I just loop through each XML element and write a corresponding Form Element for it, whether it requires a simple textbox or Radio button is determined mostly by what the datatype is...
Lets take a look at some simple Validation code I have in there...

```
    @class = "{validate:true, " + paths[i] + ":true, messages:{required:'Please enter a value'}}"
```

As you can see, I create a class that has some validation code inside of it?  This would be an answer to one of my previous stack Overflow questions, and I will be sure to fill it out when I have completely finished this site, but I digress.
Here is my simple yet elegant code that is supposed to be trivial...

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".temp1").validate();
    });
```

That should work right?  Well I get the impression that it doesn't work because my Modal window won't pop up with this jquery code running.  That is the first clue that I have the something is amiss.  If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at it quickly, but if you're trying to run the validation code try using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".temp1").valid();
});
```